# Setting a default title for bookmarks on the home screen of iOS devices?

Tags: ios, web-applications, bookmarks

when setting a default image for bookmarks on the home screen for iOS devices using

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="bla.png"/>
```

the title of the bookmark is always a chunked part of the web app's title.
Is there any chance to set a default title which is automatically presented in the "add to home screen" dialog?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: This would make sense, can't see why this would not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title is automatically set from the title in the head section.

Check this [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) for more info.

Comment: Document link is broken

Answer (score 30):

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Title">
```

Comment: This works, but only for iOS 6 and above.